# How to add Usercontrol to ItemsControl using multithread?

Tags: wpf, multithreading, user-controls

I want to set items(UserControl) to ItemsControl using multithread. My code likes this

```
System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(SetItemsControl));
    thread.Start();

    void SetItemsControl()
    {
        IDictionary<string, object> list = GetUserControlList(); // this function return list of UserControl
        this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new Action(delegate()
            {
                mylistcontrol.ItemsSource = list;

            }));
    }
```

And it breaks at my initialize function of my usercontrol

> The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this.

How can i fix it??

Comment: you can try setting thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA); before starting it. Bu i'm not sure if this will cause other problems

Comment: Yes. I tried. A threading problem occurred.
The calling thread cannot access this object because a different thread owns it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do it is to update the collection that is bound to `ItemsControl.ItemsSource`. In this scenario you do not touch the visual element from another thread - you update the collection that is bound to it. The collection being updated tells the binding to refresh and that's when data comes to UI, and it happens already in UI thread so it's ok. Note that collection should implement `INotifyCollectionChanged` interface to be able to do that

Comment: I use ObservableCollection<object> to store collection and binding it to ItemsControl. But the same error happened.

Comment: I added RootData class.  
`private ObservableCollection<object> list = new ObservableCollection<object>();
public void AddFriend(List<object> _list)
        {
            if (_list!= null)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < _list.Count; i++)
                {
                    list.Add(_list[i]);
                }
            }
        }
`
  In SetItemsControl function, i changed to  
`this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal,
            new Action(delegate()
            {
                rootdata.AddFriend(list);

            }));`

Comment: And the ItemsControl's ItemsSource is bound to RootData.list, right? And still it breaks?

Comment: Yes. I am thinking about MVVM pattern. MultiThreading will update collection in ViewModel layer. So i should not create UserControl in multithread.